# Absolute continuity of measures on a square

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a finite Borel measure on $[0, 1]\times[0, 1]$. Does there exist a finite Borel measure $\nu$ on $[0, 1]$ such that $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\nu\times\nu$?

Comment: I'm pretty sure thats not what you look for, but what about $\nu(A)=\infty$ if $A\neq \emptyset$ and $\nu(\emptyset)=0$? Caratheodory's criterion garantuees you, that every set is $\nu$-measurable, so it is a Borel measure.

Comment: I had to say that the measures are finite. Edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $\mu$ the uniform measure on the diagonal
$$\Delta = \{ (x,x) \ | x \in [0,1]\}$$
Suppose that $\mu$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. the product measure of some $\nu$ with Radon-Nykodim derivative $f$. Then we would have for $b\ge a$:
$$b-a= \int_a^b f(x,x) \nu(\{x\}) \nu(dx)$$
Now we can divide $\nu$ in a singular and an absolutely continuous part w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$. By the presence of the term $\nu(\{x\})$ we see that the integral w.r.t. the absolutely continuous part is zero. On the other side we are left with the possibility that the Lebesgue measure has a R.N. derivative w.r.t. the singular part. Which is not possible. Thus such a $\nu$ cannot exist.

Comment: Many thanks for such a simple example!

Comment: By similar logic you can see that $\mu$ is not absolutely continuous to any $\nu_1 \times \nu_2$ when at least one of the $\nu_i$ is $\sigma$-finite.